# jquery looping array of arrays on $.ajax request

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have an ajax request polling my server every 5 seconds which returns a json array of data that is available for an users shopping carts contents.

The json is correctly formed and is being returned everytime without problem.

JSON

```
[
    {
        "status": "success",
        "responsecode": "00",
        "data": [
            {
                "partnumber": "Part 1",
                "status": "true",
                "quantity": "4",
                "productid": "item-1",
                "name": "Product 2",
                "online": "1"
            },
            {
                "partnumber": "Part 2",
                "status": "false",
                "quantity": "0",
                "productid": "item-2",
                "name": "Product 2",
                "online": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Jquery function to process the ajax response

```
function doPoll(){   
    $.ajax({
           type: "get",
           url: "/assets/static-pages/shopping-cart/?action=check-cart",           
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(html) {
            $.each(html, function(key, value) 
                {
                    console.log(value.data[key].partnumber);
                }
             );
             }
    });
    //   setTimeout(doPoll,10000);
}
```

every time it loops, all it does is return the first item in the array, I would very much like to loop the array and return all that resides within the "data" array so I can manipulate the UI based on its contents, but for some reason I cant figure out how to get all the data.

any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: Note that the JSON response start with [ that means it is an array, and you should considering it in the success (ponting to an index)

Answer (score 1):

Your json is an array, so you have to access it with an index, this case `0`.
Then you don't need to access it using `key`, because it'll loop thrue each data object, so it's stored into `value`.

```
$.each(html[0].data, function(key, value) {
    console.log( value.partnumber );
});
```